# Loading gem at runtime in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have Rails 3.0.x application. I would like to load gems on runtime, without using `Gemfile`.

What I would like to accomplish is to load my application as usual, with regular gems being loaded by Bundler. After that I would like to load all gems (Rails Engines) located in a specific directory (but until runtime, I don't know what gems will that be).

Does anybody know if this is possible in Rails, maybe using Bundler API?

Comment: Out of curiosity: could you explain the use-case? It is not clear to me why you would want to do this.

Comment: The idea was to have modular Rails application that would load it's modules on runtime. I wanted to put modules/gems into directory, start application and be flexible :)

Comment: Okay, I am assuming you have some generic rails app which you install at the client-site, and based on some options (fee/license), install the correct modules in the folder. But what if you just edit the Gemfile, and to bundle install? It is less work, it is safer, and the only ediiting/configuration was editing the Gemfile. That is what we do. We host our own gemserver for our own "private" gems. If a module is enabled or disabled, we just edit the Gemfile, bundle and restart.

Comment: Of course, this is one of the options and this is what was done at the end (keep in mind that this question wasn't asked recently). But being  able to load modules on runtime somehow would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do is dangerous. If each of your Rails Engines are also gems - then they would also have Gemfiles with other dependencies, and those would in turn have other dependencies, etc. If you allow Bundler to resolve those, then you would have lesser problems at runtime.

Here's how you would do it *without any hacks*. Remember that your `Gemfile` is just Ruby code, and you can have gems which are not loaded by default.

```
# In your Gemfile, add at the end:
Dir[YOUR_RAILS_ENGINES_SUBFOLDER + "/*/*.gemspec"].each do |gemspec_file|
  dir_name = File.dirname(gemspec_file)
  gem_name = File.basename(gemspec_file, File.extname(gemspec_file))

  # sometimes "-" and "_" are used interchangeably in gems
  # for e.g. gemspec_file is "engines/my-engine/my_engine.gemspec"
  #   dir_name will be engines/my-engine
  #   gem_name will be my_engine

  # Register that engine as a dependency, *without* being required
  gem gem_name, :path => dir_name, :require => false

  # e.g. this is similar to saying
  #  gem 'my_engine', :path => 'engines/my-engine', :require => false
end
```

Now you have all your dynamic Rails engines registered as gem dependencies. Bundler will resolve them, and all their sub-dependencies, so you don't have to worry about anything. Just run `bundle install` once before running the application, or whenever you add/remove any engine in that folder.

The good thing is, these gems will *just* be registered, and not loaded. So in your production code, you can now load whatever gem that you choose at runtime simply by saying `require <your-engine-name>`

Edit: Extra code comments

Comment: Nice, I asked this question 1.5 year ago and I'm not using Rails anymore, but I think this is what I was looking for and it could actually work. Thanks

Comment: I'm not the OP but I did start the bounty for this question. The question as asked was how to dynamically load engines in runtime, not at startup. If loading at startup was enough then a simpler approach would be to call Bundler.load_gemspec from boot.rb.

Comment: This code is far from loading the gems *dynamically*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  # require gems...
end
```

Comment: I tried that before and I don't know if I'm missing something but if I add this line to `boot.rb` I get error: `'my_gem' is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.`

Comment: What do you mean by writing: `# require gems...`, maybe this is what I am missing?